# Not able to mock static methods using Powermock (with EasyMock)

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock, powermock

I want to mock a static method and also non-static methods of a class.
  My source looks like:

`public class XDSUtilityManager
    {

        private static XDSUtilityManager xdsUtilMgr = new XDSUtilityManager();
        private XDSUtilityManager()
        {
            xdsUtilMgrImpl = new XDSUtilityManagerImpl();
        }

        public static XDSUtilityManager getInstance()
        {
            return (xdsUtilMgr == null ) ? new XDSUtilityManager() : xdsUtilMgr;
        }
        public XMLDocument getXMLDocument(final String absoluteKey, final XDSClient xdsClient)
        {
            return getXMLDocument(absoluteKey, xdsClient, false);
        }
    }`

I want to mock static method **getInstance()**. I want getInstance() to return mock object of **XDSUtilityManager** class.  Also I want to mock **getXMLDocument()** which is not static.

And in my testCase I tried following:

`XMLDocument xmlDocument = PowerMock.createMock(XMLDocument.class);

XDSUtilityManager xdsUtilityManager  = PowerMock.createPartialMock(XDSUtilityManager.class,"getXMLDocument");

PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(XDSUtilityManager.class, "getInstance");
expect(XDSUtilityManager.getInstance()).andReturn(xdsUtilityManager).anyTimes();

expect(xdsUtilityManager.getXMLDocument((String)anyObject(), anyObject(XDSClient.class))).andReturn(xmlDocument).anyTimes();

PowerMock.replay(xdsUtilityManager);
PowerMock.replay(xmlDocument);`

But things are not working as expected. Please help

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I have found to do this is by using [PowerMockito](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13).  PowerMockito is a combination of Mockito and PowerMock, which allows the mocking of static objects.

The pattern I have used is to use the mock your static `getInstance()` to return a copy of your non static mock, which you then extend as normal.  An example using [PowerMockito](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html) would be:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SingletonObject.class})
public class SingletonTester {
  @Mock
  private SingletonObject singleMock;

  @Before
  public void setup(){
      // initialize all the @Mock objects
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      // mock all the statics
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(SingletonObject.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void mockTester(){
      // Mock the static getInstance call to return the non-Static Mock
      Mockito.when(SingletonObject.getInstance()).thenReturn(singleMock);

      // Mock the non static version as normal
      PowerMockito.when(singleMock.nonStaticMethodCall()).thenReturn("Whatever you need.");
      //..........
  }
}
```

Your static call to `getInstance()` to get the singleton object returns the instantiated mock object you ALSO define.  Once you tell the static what to return, you can continue to mock the non-static calls as normal.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Its not required to call `getInstance()` method to create the instance of `XDSUtilityManager`.
Using `PowerMockito`, as your constructor is private you need to `suppress the constructor` before you call create mock as below..

```
PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(XDSUtilityManager.class));
// enable static mocking for all the methods in the class   
PowerMockito.mockStatic(XDSUtilityManager.class); 
XDSUtilityManager xDSUtilityManager =  PowerMockito.mock(XDSUtilityManager.class);
XMLDocument xmlDocument = PowerMock.createMock(XMLDocument.class); 
PowerMockito.when(xDSUtilityManager.getXMLDocument(
    Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(xmlDocument);
```